# ComboBox SelectedValue doesn't show

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-8, viewmodel, windows-runtime

I have a strange problem in my WinRT/C# XAML Metro app, using the Windows 8 Release Preview (latest patches installed). I'm using a `ComboBox`, whose values `ItemsSource` and `SelectedValue` are bound to properties in a ViewModel:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
          Width="200" Height="30" />
```

Code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new TestViewModel();
}
```

And a very simple definition of the `TestViewModel`, using strings:

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private IEnumerable<string> _myItemsSource = new List<string>
        {
            "Test Item 1",
            "Test Item 2",
            "Test Item 3"
        };
    public IEnumerable<string> MyItemsSource
    {
        get { return _myItemsSource; }
    }

    private string _mySelectedValue = "Test Item 2";
    public string MySelectedValue
    {
        get { return _mySelectedValue; }
        set
        {
            _mySelectedValue = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MySelectedValue"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I thought this simple solution should just work... But when I start the app, the `SelectedValue="Test Item 2"` doesn't show up, the `ComboBox` is left empty. By setting breakpoints I noticed that the bound values `MyItemsSource` and `MySelectedValue` are corectly retrieved from the View Model when I set the `DataContext` of the view. After this action, the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` property is actually set to `"Test Item 2"`, but it just doesn't show! Also I noticed that when I change the selected value in the ComboBox by user action on the UI, the changed value shows up in the ComboBox and the View Model property is updated accordingly. So everything seems to work fine except the initial visualization of the `MySelectedValue` View Model property. I'm becoming really desperate about that...

Now while this is the simplest example, in the origin I wanted to bind whole entities to ComboBox, setting `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath`. Unfortunately, the same problem occurs.

Comment: is that work for you ???

Comment: Does the problem persist if you get an actual element from the collection, instead of assigning "a new string" to selectedValue, as in `selectedValue = itemsSource[1]`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the problem in my example: In the XAML markup I've defined the `SelectedValue` property **before** the `ItemsSource` property. If I swap both definitions in this way, it works:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
      SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
      Width="200" Height="30" />
```

This is really odd and annoying. Now I would like to know: is this a bug or by design? I think this is a bug, because the control should be working regardless of the order of the defined properties in XAML.

Comment: this was since Silverlight 2.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've been using Silverlight/WPF/Windows8 for years and never noticed the order of binding matters. Recently I ran into this issue while developing a Windows8 app, it took me a while to realize the `SelectedValue` was before `ItemsSource` binding.

Comment: really?  I didn't think this mattered

Comment: This is so true and so annoying!

Comment: o_O  Microsoft just trolling us.

Answer (score 2):

this is working solution : you can find here https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=b55690d11b67401d&resid=B55690D11B67401D!209&id=B55690D11B67401D!209

```
<ComboBox Width="300" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>
```

ViewModle class is

```
public class ViewModel:BaseViewModel
    {
        private Person selectedPerson;
        public Person SelectedPerson {
            get { return this.selectedPerson; }
            set { this.selectedPerson = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonCollection { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.PersonCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            this.PopulateCollection();

            //setting first item as default one
            this.SelectedPerson = this.PersonCollection.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        private void PopulateCollection()
        {
            this.PersonCollection.Add(new Person { Name="Oscar", Email="oscar@sl.net" });
            this.PersonCollection.Add(new Person { Name = "Jay", Email = "jay@sl.net" });
            this.PersonCollection.Add(new Person { Name = "Viral", Email = "viral@sl.net" });
        }
    }
```